# Slick column type of Any in Scala

Tags: scala, slick

I have the following question:

```
case class User(id: String, name: String, value: Any, userId: String)
```

and I want to create the table Users.

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "USERS"){
  def id = column[String]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("NAME")
  def value = column[Any]("VALUE")
  def userId = column[String]("USER_ID")

  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * = (id.?, name, value, userId) <> (Fact.tupled, Fact.unapply _)
}
```

However I got an error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[Any]
Not enought arguments for method column:(implicit slick.ast.TypedType[Any])slick.lifted.Rep[Any]
```

I think that I can not define Any as column type in slick or the case is different?

Comment: Well you could use `java.sql.Blob`, however I wouldn't recommend that. Storing `Any` in a DB is probably not the best idea. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually the value could be anything in that application, a string.. a number.. anything.. How can I store that kind of variable in a database?

Comment: If anything means primitive types only, you can save them as string. But again, this is bad practice. Your software design seems to be flawed. Actually you should almost never use `Any` (with emphasis on never). Have you considered adding related DB tables? It also might be helpful if you tell a little bit more about your use case. Why does `value` have to be be of type `Any`?

Comment: Agree with @Roman.  You may consider to use a JSON object instead of Any.